# Aliases held inside bashrc file not working despite working yesterday and echo ~ returns /h/

Tags: bash, git

I have a number of bash aliases stored within my .bashrc file that I use to quickly navigate to different Git repositories. Here are some examples of my aliases (not my actual repo names):

```
alias repo1='cd /c/source/repo1/'
alias repo2='cd /c/source/repo2/'
alias repo3='cd /c/source/repo3/'
```

Up until yesterday these aliases were working correctly. However today when I try to use any of them I get `bash: repo1: command not found`

I've had a look at some other SO questions and have tried to use the `. ~/.bashrc` command, however I get this in response:

```
bash: /h//.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

And then when I try to do `echo ~` I get:

```
/h/
```

Which obviously isn't my `c:\users\<userName>\` directory that my .bashrc file is stored inside.

How can I fix this?

Edit: Just on top of this.

I have a number of aliases also stored inside my .gitconfig file. These aliases aren't working either. And git has prompted me with a message that says I haven't chosen a difftool when inside my .gitconfig I have

```
[difftool "p4merge"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
```

So it seems as though my config files aren't being loaded correctly. I have restarted and this problem is still persisting.

Comment: How is bash installed/configured? Your `$HOME` isn't being set correctly, it seems, or being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: @muru It's strange, because I haven't installed or made any changes in the last 24 hours that could have caused this problem. My bash was installed along with the git installer when I installed git.

Comment: Try `export HOME="c:\\users\\<userName>"` and see if that fixes anything. If so, maybe add it to the end of your bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix this problem, for anyone else that needs an answer.

It seemed as though @Muru was right, and that my `$HOME` directory had somehow been changed.

To fix this, I navigated to Window's environmental variables settings and then set a new user variable with the following details:

```
Variable name: HOME
Variable value: C:\users\<user_name>
```

After this I closed and reopened git bash, and my aliases were working again.